# How does Anticipate Teleportation Greater affect someone walking through a Dimension Door?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, teleportation

**Anticipate Telep. Greater states:**

> As anticipate teleportation, except that greater anticipate
>   teleportation identifies the type of the arriving creature (and any
>   companions accompanying it) and creates a delay of 3 rounds, providing
>   the recipient with even more warning and preparation time.

Dimension door... is a bit longer but states you can teleport on the same plane.

My question is: what happens to the guy which is doing dimension door, or any telep on the same plane while it's telep-ing like from 30 feets away?

Does he stay 3 rounds in the nothingness while he teleps the 30 feets?

Comment: I got a vision of 30 feet pouring out of a dimensional door when it opens...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The spell affects all teleportation effects with their destinations inside the spell's area, including teleportation effects used by nearby creatures and allies

The 3rd-level spell *anticipate teleportation* [abjur] (*SpC* 13) *et al.* says that

> The subject of the spell is surrounded with an invisible aura that anticipates and delays the teleportation of any creature into the spell’s area. Any teleportation spell or effect (including all spells with the teleportation descriptor) can be anticipated, making the spell’s recipient instantly aware of the exact location where the teleporting creature
>   will arrive (subject to the restrictions below), the creature’s size, and how many other creatures (and their sizes) are arriving with the teleporting creature.
>
> The spell also delays the arrival of the teleporting creature by 1 round (so that it arrives on its initiative count immediately before its next turn), generally giving the recipient of the spell and anyone else made aware of the information 1 round to act or ready actions. The teleporting creature does not perceive this delay. [...]
>
> The spell has no effect on creatures attempting to teleport away from the spell’s area, although if their destination is within the area, the spell will affect their reentry as normal.

If the creature's teleportation destination is inside the effect of an *anticipate teleportation* spell, the creature's teleportation effect is delayed, whether the creature is using a teleportation effect from, for example, 10 ft. away, 100 ft. away, light years away, or another plane.<sup>1</sup> Spell resistance, caster level, and the level of the spell used to generate the teleportation effect make no difference to the *anticipate teleportation* spells.<sup>2</sup>

> ### True Story
>
> The paladin PC needs to save the lady in distress from the dastardly sorcerer. The paladin PC employs his Use Magic Device skill to activate his *wand of benign transposition*, trying to swap places with the lady in distress. The paladin PC and the lady in distress are unaware that their destinations are *both* in the area of the rogue/wizard PC's *greater anticipate teleportation* spell. Both the paladin PC and the lady no-longer-in distress are out of action for the next 3 rounds, and upon their returns find the dastardly sorcerer gone; the fighter PC on the ground, helpless, having been reduced to 0 Str; and the rogue/wizard *baleful polymorphed* into a cat.

The *anticipate teleportation* spell line is an essential element for keeping mundane folks alive past level 6 in an optimized environment, but be sure to tell your party members that the spell's on--it's duration is 24 hours, and [it's not dismissible](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/49183/8610), meaning that usually resources have to be devoted to making it go away early. The spell can be just as dangerous to party members as it is to foes.

---

1. All the spell *stand* [conj] (*PH2* 125-6) does is make a prone creature upright, but it's a teleportation spell therefore affected by the spell *anticipate teleport*, too!
2. There *is* that pregnant-with-meaning *can* in spell description's second sentence, but the spell makes no further mention of it being in any way a controllable or selective, so the use of *can* there should not be mistaken for the caster being able to allow some teleportation effects and disallow others but simply read as a helping verb. Yes, that could be clearer, but the spell provides no mechanism of choosing *not* to anticipate a teleportation effect anyway.

Comment: ... and the paladin smiles the satisfied smile of the doer of good works. "A job well done, I say."

Comment: Wait, it's an *actual* true story?

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton O, yes. Everyone *thought* the *benign transposition* was brilliant, and it wasn't until after the spell was cast that I asked what spells folks had on, only then remembering I'd heard mention of *greater anticipate teleportation* earlier in the session. The paladin's player is old school cool and just manned up: "It's what my character would've done, and I should've been paying better attention."

Comment: What if the char with Ant.Telep teleps 30 feets?

Comment: The spell may not be dismissible in the normal way, but... `Focus: A tiny hourglass of platinum and crystal costing 500 gp, which must be carried or worn by the spell's recipient while the spell is in effect.` you can just chuck the focus away and the effect immediately ends.

Comment: @Yandros  What that means, though, is up to the DM. Although it says that hourglass focus "must be carried or worn by the spell's recipient while the spell is in effect" it doesn't answer *Or else...?* Does the spell end if it's not? Is the spell suppressed while it's not carried or worn and resumes when it is? Is a *broken* hourglass in the caster's possession *still* hourglass-y enough for the spell to continue? I dunno, and the game doesn't say.

Comment: @Yandros While I'm AFB and as such can't give a definitive answer to the rest, one thing is clear: if the hourglass `must be carried or worn by the spell's recipient while the spell is in effect`, and the recipient ceases to carry the hourglass, then the spell is no longer in effect.

Comment: so when you telep and you have a fear aura on yourself lets all your enemies a new ST? I've asked this here: to not go off topic with the main question. http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50105/how-does-anticipate-teleportation-greater-affect-yourself

Comment: You're assuming that the effect of the spell only applies right before the moment when the creature arrives. In a particular moment that in many teleport spells doesn't even _exist_ without this spell in effect. (Stand is an immediate effect, for example. You're never "in transit" if there is no effect that delays you.)

Comment: Wouldn't be proper. I'm his DM :P

Comment: @Yandros +1 Hurray for my DM! =D LOL, however I would like you to answer and see how many upvotes you get =P

Comment: @Yandros I think I addressed everything (but the necessity of house ruling the hourglass) in [another answer](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/50105/8610). I'm deleting my now irrelevant comments. Turns out, after some research, I changed my mind.