# How does Anticipate Teleportation Greater affect yourself?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, teleportation

This is a great one, that comes from here: [How does Anticipate Teleportation Greater affect someone walking through a Dimension Door?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49957/how-does-anticipate-teleportation-greater-affect-someone-walking-through-a-dimen) and [Anticipate Teleportation on yourself](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Rec/rec.games.frp.dnd/2007-07/msg00697.html).

So... you are inside your own area of effect and use the spell *Stand* on yourself.

Does the effect go with you or stay there because that is instant?

What if you use *Dimension Door* to teleport to somewhere inside the area?

What if someone actively teleports you inside your AoE? For example using *Dimension Hop*, *Benign Transposition*, or *Baleful Transposition*?

Assume you send someone 3 rounds to nothingness from teleporting. If you teleport out of that place before those 3 rounds pass, does that effect end or continue the whole 3 rounds?

If you go down the "the effect disappears with you" path, what happens with other area effects like "fear aura" when you teleport like 30 feet? sShould your enemies get another ST?.

Answer (score 3):

## The target of the spell *anticipate teleportation* delays itself if it uses a teleportation effect

An emanation affects the subject of the emanation as if he were within the emanation's area. The 3rd-level Sor/Wiz spell *anticipate teleportation* [abjur] (*SpC* 13) *et al.* doesn't say otherwise.

The Area entry of the spell *anticipate teleportation* uses language like the Area entries of the 3rd-level Clr spells [*magic circle against* alignment](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magicCircleAgainstEvil.htm) [abjur] (*PH* 249-50), which clearly affect creatures within the spell's area *including* the spell's target. Contrast this with the spell *eye of the hurricane* [abjur] (*SpC* 86-7), which details the effects of a metaphorical dead zone around the caster wherein he and those nearby function normally and those beyond the dead zone are tossed about by hurricane-strength winds.

### Answers

1. The spell *stand* [conj] (*PH2* 125-6) is in the teleportation subschool (*PH* 173) therefore qualifying as a "teleportation spell or effect" as per the description of the spell *anticipate teleportation*. A creature that is the target of the spell *anticipate teleportation* that then casts the spell *stand* on itself would find its return delayed, its destination (*its own space*) within the area of its own *anticipate teleportation* spell. The *anticipate teleportation* effect travels with the creature on whom it's cast and disappears while the creature's delayed.

   Because the spell belongs to the teleportation subschool, *I* imagine the spell *stand*-- despite its name and opening descriptive text--*actually* teleporting the target from prone to upright, instead of merely allowing the target to regain his footing somehow without provoking attacks of opportunity. Ask the DM if he reads the spell differently.
2. The 4th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*dimension door*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/dimensionDoor.htm) [conj] (*PH* 221) is *also* in the teleportation subschool, so it, too, is affected by the creature's own *anticipate teleportation* spell--excluding weirdness--*no matter his destination.* The creature's destination will be somewhere the creature will be, after all.
3. If a creature that is the target of the spell *anticipate teleportation* is affected by a teleportation effect against its will the creature will be delayed by the *anticipate teleportation* effect--again, excluding weirdness--*no matter his destination.*
4. Incoming creatures are delayed the appropriate amount of time by the spell *anticipate teleportation et al.* even if the target emanating the *anticipate teleportation* effect has since moved the emanation's area to a where the effect's area no longer covers the delayed creature's destination. The spell does the delaying upon the destination being within its area, independent of the creature being sure to continue covering that area with the effect.
5. If an effect occurs when a creature is near and the creature departs and returns--no matter how brief that departure is--, such an effect *should* occur again. However, if the creature's departure *corresponds* to its return--that is, if there's *no time* between its departure and return--, then nothing about the situation's changed, and such an effect *shouldn't* again occur. "Teleportation is instantaneous travel through the Astral Plane" (*PH* 173), and, as such, teleportation is *both* departure and return **and** there's no time between. In other words, ask the DM.

Information about how emanations function is sparse. Answers 1 through 3 are predicated on the *anticipate teleportation* spells' emanations functioning like the *magic circle against* alignment spells' emanations. If there's a reason the *anticipate teleportation* spells should function *differently* from those, I am happy to be wrong--personally, I think it sucks that one's *anticipate teleportation* effect interferes with one's own teleportation effects but, I guess, such is the price of security.

Comment: I'm not fully convinced by this answer. According to this conversation https://forums.giantitp.com/showthread.php?272605-3-5-Anticipate-teleport-spell-Explanations-Clarifications (not official, but makes sense to me), since the emanation is centered on you, and not on a physical point in the material plane, when you travel in any way, the emanation travels with you, so during your teleportation, no one is affected against the emanation. So if you go to outer planes e.g. with planeshift the emanation does not stay in the material plane. In that same way should your own teleports affect you.

Comment: @apacay It's really the kind of thing the spell should make clear; we can only speculate. I think it's consistent with the game's rules that a creature is affected by its own emanation unless the spell says that it's not. Thus when the creature that's teleporting has itself a *greater anticipate teleportation* effect running, the creature's arrival point *would be* within its emanation—I mean, it *must* be, right? However, I'm not entirely clear on the comment. I don't think that I implied, for instance, that the spell's effect activates anew while the subject is gone, did I?