# What published source contained antimagic oozes?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e, product-identification, epic-tier

So, I was talking with a friend about [how to disable divine casters in D&D 3.5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/182112/denying-npc-divine-casters-the-ability-to-regain-spells), and they raised an intriguing possibility in that an unfortunate encounter with something called an "antimagic ooze" could do the job. However, they weren't able to provide a citation for it, just the following details:

- It projects an antimagic field for a ~30' radius about it
- Touching it makes the toucher permanently lose their ability to cast spells
- It apparently is an (epic-level) trap, not a creature?
- They recall it being in a Dragon Magazine somewhere, possibly as a variation on the Flux Slime epic hazard published in the D&D 3.5e SRD

Where was this published (if anywhere)?

Answer (score 2):

#### I think they're actually mis-remembering the flux slime.

The *Epic Level Handbook* came out in July 2002. Epic level content wasn't previewed in Dragon until issue #294 in April 2002, and switched to 4e after #363. If it did appear in *Dragon*, it appeared within that 69-issue range.

Of those, [Dragondex](https://www.aeolia.net/dragondex/articles-subject.html) only lists issues 295, 306, and 324 as having articles on traps, and 297 and 308 as having articles on epic content. I checked all five, and none reference an antimagic ooze. I also thought they may be thinking of *Dungeon*, but according to the index in issue #150, the only *Dungeon* issue with an epic-level adventure is #123 with *Quicksilver Hourglass*, which I checked and it has no antimagic ooze.

However, the [flux slime](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/obstacles.htm#fluxSlime), from the Epic Level Handbook, meets most of their requirements, if we allow for a degree of misremembering specific details. It radiates an antimagic field (though only to ten feet, not thirty), specially harms spellcasters (although causes Constitution damage rather than forgotten spells), rather causes magic items to permanently lose their magic, and is an epic level trap or hazard rather than a creature.